# How to identify an element by classname that keeps changing using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, pageobjects

I am trying to locate a buttons element, but every time my test run the element keeps on changing name. The class keeps changing the last digits. For Example, `jss2383`  to `jss4132` as well as all elements within the button class. My alternative solution is by using the xpath to find it by text.

```
<div class="jss2383">
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root-2225 MuiButton-root-2198 MuiButton-contained-2206 MuiButton-containedPrimary-2207" tabindex="0" type="button">
   <span class="MuiButton-label-2199">Refresh</span>
   <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-2395"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

What I have so far to find the element is the following. The reason I want to locate the element by class name is because the button can either be a refresh or an import.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Refresh']")
WebElement refreshButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the class value changes dynamically, So you can use contains function

```
@FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(@class,'MuiButton-label')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

These *classnames* i.e. *`jss2383`*, *`jss4132`* are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

As you mentioned *"...the button can either be a refresh or an import..."* you can use either of the following locators:

- Using *xpath1*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath="//button//span[text()='Refresh' or text()='Import']")
  WebElement refreshImportButton;
  ```
- Using *xpath2*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath="//button//span[starts-with(@class, 'MuiButton-label')][text()='Refresh' or text()='Import']")
  WebElement refreshImportButton;
  ```